# Regular Expressions: Lookback to only the first occurrence (non-greedy lookback?)

Tags: regex

Here's the problem:

XML:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewPublicReports</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewSetup</name>
</userPermissions>
```

What I'm trying to match is:

```
<userPermissions>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
    <name>ViewRoles</name>
</userPermissions>
```

All the patterns that I've managed to put together matches up to the first  string:

```
(?<=<userPermissions>)[\s\S]+?ViewRoles[\s\S]*?<\/userPermissions>
```

Not quite sure how to make the backwards match from "ViewRoles" non-greedy.

Thanks in advance for your help.

*Edit: I'm using a tool that deploys metadata between Salesforce instances, which are captured as XML. The tool provides a "find/replace" functionality that uses regex for the "find." I don't have the option of using an XML parser.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse XML with a regex? Just use a real XML parser.

Comment: What language is this for?

Comment: Anyone know why I got docked for this question? I spent a few hours researching. I get that one would ideally use an XML parser, but this is still a legitimate question on using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `<userPermissions>(?:(?!</userPermissions>)[\S\s])*?ViewRoles[\S\s]*?</userPermissions>`

matches that tag.

[Formatted](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 <userPermissions>
 (?:
      (?! </userPermissions> )
      [\S\s] 
 )*?
 ViewRoles
 [\S\s]*? 
 </userPermissions>
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been told, but the correct way to extract this would be to use an XML parser. However, you can also use [the following regex](https://regex101.com/r/OFLhyv/1):

```
(.+\n){2}.+ViewRoles.+\n.+
```

Which actually matches the following structure:

- 2 rows without restrictions
- a row that includes "ViewRoles"
- another row without restrictions

Comment: I was hoping for something dynamic rather than counting lines. The solution I used before posting the question was `<userPermissions>.*\n.*\n.*(ViewRoles)(\s|\S)*?<\/userPermissions>`, but I was trying to find a string that wouldn't rely on the number of lines, but rather just "match up to the most recent instance of _some string_"

Comment: The line counting is meant to add the whole `userPermissions` tag to the returned value. If you want only the first appearance of a string just don't use the `/g` flag. Is that what you mean?